# How can I tell Vim to show ANSI escape codes properly?

Tags: vim, escape-characters

I'm trying to view and edit a file in Vim, but this file has ANSI escape codes:

```
^[[1m[0.05s elapsed, 00:00:13 total]^[[0m
```

How can I tell Vim to interpret them properly instead of just showing the raw code?

Comment: What does "interpret properly" mean?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-make-vim-display-colors-as-indicated-by-color-codes (not dupe because he wants Vim as a pager)

Comment: @wallyk: It means I want to see colors and effects, not raw codes.

Comment: See the answer at https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20496/3324: *“If you have a sufficiently modern vim that has the +terminal feature, you can do `:term cat somefile` and you'll get a buffer with all the terminal codes interpreted.

This might work better on large files than e.g. Colorizer, which made my vim unusably slow when I let it loose on a 6000-line file.”*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you want to display ANSI colors and conceal their escape characters.  You can do this with Charles Campbell's "[AnsiEsc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302)" plugin.

Note that you will need Vim version 7.3 or newer. (Older versions of Vim could be patched, but that's more work for an outdated version of Vim.)

Comment: This works, if the file is in a buffer. However it doesn't work great if you are running a command like rake or cucumber that puts the command output not in a buffer.

Comment: That is correct, but the asker specifically mentioned ANSI within a file opened in Vim.